# Redirect pop up when downloading file in Lightning tab

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

There are two components: One Vf Page - VfParent, second an LWC componenet - LWCChild.

The component is embedded inside the VF page using the use "$Lightning.use". Everything works as expected.

```javascript
<apex:page >
  <apex:includeLightning /> 
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("cpint:LWCChild", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            "cpint:LWCChild",
            {dummyVal:dumToken},
    
            "ConfigSetting",
            function(cmp) {
                lwcCmp = cmp;
                
        }); })
 </script>
 
</apex: page>
```

I added the vf page inside a lightning tab.
So when I have to downlaod a file, I click on the download file button I get the following pop up that leads to nothing ( P.S - I did give all the permission from the browser but that doesn't work).

[image: The Rendered LWC component]
[image: This pop up shows up when we click on the download button when the Tab is opened, if we only open the Vf page in new window then the file gets downloaded without any pop-up]

whereas if you open the vf page in a new window (marked in yellow in below image) rather than in the lightning tab, you can download the file without any issues. So, this issue only exists in the Lightning tab context, any idea what might be causing the same?
[image]

JS on the LWCChild

```javascript
downloadDummyFile() {   
    var saveData = (function () {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            return function (data, fileName) {
                blob = new Blob([(json)], {type: "application/json"}),
                url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            };
        }());
        let data = { key: 'value' };
        let fileName = 'This is my custom filename.txt';
        saveData(data, fileName);
        
    }
}
```

HTML on the LWCChild.

```html
<template>
    <lightning-tabset>
        <lightning-tab label="Testing the download">                
            <button onclick={downloadDummyFile}>Download Dummy File</button>
        </lightning-tab>      
</lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

Comment: how are you able to embed lwc in vf directly? and when are you calling downloadDummyFile. 
Please share your whole code.

Comment: @MukulMahawariya , Hey sorry for the confusion. We can use the lightning inside the script of the vf page as mentioned above, as per the reasoning as to why this is done is something I don't know as such. 
I'm calling the donwloadDummyFile when we click on that button. Please let me know if you need any more information.